# Why normalize() method doesn't work in some cases?

Tags: javascript, normalize

By default, `String.prototype.normalize()` uses `NFC` as an argument. `NFC` replaces multiple characters with single one.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize#canonical_equivalence_normalization)

> You can specify "NFC" to get the composed canonical form, in which
> multiple code points are replaced with single code points where
> possible.

And here's an example from MDN. It works.

```js
let str = '\u006E\u0303';
str = str.normalize();
console.log(`${str}: ${str.length}`);
```

But then I decided to try this method with other characters. For example:

```js
let str = '\u0057\u0303';
str = str.normalize();
console.log(`${str}: ${str.length}`);
```

What's wrong in the second example? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Maybe because the single character W̃ doesn't exist in unicode (and further, because no language on earth uses this character)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't replace multiple **characters** it replaces multiple **codepoints** and only **where possible**.

`ñ`, being [a character used in Spanish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%91) has its own codepoint in unicode: — U+00D1 — so you can just say `ñ` instead of "Take an `n` and then put a `~` on top of it".

`W̃`, being [a representation of a phonic sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasal_labial%E2%80%93velar_approximant) doesn't have its own codepoint. It is a character used comparatively rarely so hasn't been given precious space in the more efficient bits of Unicode. The only way you can have one is to say "Take a `W` and then put a `~` on top of it".

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought about that, but then I decided to check if this charachter has its own codepoint by using method `codePointAt()`. It returned `87`. But... afterwards, checking this returned number, I realized that `87` is for usual `W`, not `W̃`. Looks like `codePointAt` just returned the codepoint of the first character